# Why is this grammar not LL(1)

Tags: parsing, grammar

I have the next grammar:

```
C := (PZ)
P := X | C
X := iQ | eQ | rQ
Q := AX | ε
A := +
L :=  >
Z := LP | AP | ε
```

and i am using JFLAP to build an LL(1) parsing table, but at the moment that i type those rules, JFLAP throws me an error that says: the grammar is not LL(1).I have found where the mistake is, in the rule 'Q'.

The first set of Q is   Q = {+,ε},  and the follow set of Q is   Q = { ), + , >} and in the parsing table i am going to have two rules in table[Q,+] and that´s the mistake, but i dont know how to fix it because i need to have the rule Q -> ε

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that your grammar is ambiguous -- you have two nested repeating patterns from your rules for `X` and `Z` and both of them can match an `i+i` fragment.  So you need to decide how you want to resolve that ambiguity -- which way should a fragment like `i+i` match:

```
         PZ                          PZ
        /  \                        /  \
       X    ε                      X    AP
      / \                         / \  /  \
     i   Q                       i  Q  +   X
        / \                        /      / \
       A   X                      ε      i   Q
      /   / \                                |
     +   i   Q                               ε
             |
             ε
```

The easiest fix is to make it always match the right example, which you can do by just getting rid of the `X`/`Q` repeating pattern:

```
C := (PZ)
P := X | C
X := i | e | r
A := +
L :=  >
Z := LP | AP | ε
```

If you want to always match the left example, you need to disallow `+` in the `Z` pattern:

```
C := (PZ)
P := X | C
X := iQ | eQ | rQ
Q := AX | ε
A := +
L :=  >
Z := LP | ε
```